# suppressing the dialog box that pop up while unit Testing

Tags: unit-testing, mvvm, dialog

I am doing MVVM unit Test testing of view models and inside the open method there is a call to the view that pop ups the dialog box to enter the password given as the argument in the Test. Us there any way to suppress that call since the call is inside the function which is being unit Tested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply use a popup-managing system like ones found in MVVMLight, Caliburn or Prism. When unit testing, provide a mock for the system (e.g. Rhino Mocks).

Comment: hi, my application is using prism but the dialog box is in xaml inside view and i m testing view model. when i am mocking the interface required for dialog box it throws xaml exception.

Comment: Hi, could you please provide the code where you call the popup in your view-model?